# Lightning event's attribute show undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, lightning-events

I have table of records that I can click on. When click, it must fire the event then open new console tab but event attribute show undefined when tab is open for first time. My lightning event attribute is working fine when particular tab is opened.

**OrderIdEvent**

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description=""  >
<aura:attribute name = "orderId" type="String" default=""/>
</aura:event>
```

**TableCmp.cmp**

```
<aura:registerEvent name="orderEvent" type="c:OrderIdEvent"/>
```

**TableCmp.js**

```
navigateToURL: function (component, event, helper) {
        var arrList = event.target.value;
        var result = arrList.split("@");
        var selectedAccountId = result[0];
        console.log('Selected Account Id = ', selectedAccountId);
        component.set('v.accountId', selectedAccountId);
        //
        const orderEvtparam = {'orderId':'12345'};
        helper.fireOrderIdEvent('OrderIdEvent',orderEvtparam);
        var url = '/lightning/r/Account/'+selectedAccountId+'/view'; 
        var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
        workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function (response) {
        workspaceAPI.openTab({
            url: url, 
            focus: true
            }).then((response) => {
                workspaceAPI.refreshTab({
                tabId: response,
                includeAllSubtabs: true
                });
            });
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    },
```

**Tablecmp.helper**

```
fireOrderIdEvent : function(evtName,params){
        try{
        var orderEvent = $A.get("e.c:OrderIdEvent");
        orderEvent.setParams(params);
        orderEvent.fire(); 
        console.log('fire!');
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    },
```

**SecondCmp.cmp**

```
<aura:handler event="c:OrderIdEvent" action="{!c.handleEvent}" />
```

**SecondCmp.js**

```
handleEvent :function(component,event,helper){  
        var orId = event.getParam("orderId");
        console.log('orId event = ' + orId);
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax is wrong.

```
var orderEvent = $A.get("e.OrderIdEvent");
```

Just try Replacing above line in your tablecmp helper with

```
var orderEvent = $A.get("e.c:OrderIdEvent");
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: I updated the syntax already and still show undefined in first round.